# border-bottom hover length when using bootstrap navbar collapse

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When the navbar is in normal size it works as I want, but when the device is smaller, the border-bottom hover is the whole line, while I want it to be just under the word.

Normal size navbar

[image]

Smaller device navbar

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You can probably solve this by adding the class `d-inline-block` to the link to make it inline.

Comment: The d-inline-block resolved it.  Thank u so much!